# How to Create WSDL file to return ArrayList?

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws

I am retrieving data from MySql database as list.My code is When I passed table name it gives list of data based on table name. Now how to create WSDL file to my class.

Below is My code:

```
@WebService
public class GetEmployeeImpl implements GetEmployee {
EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getEmf().createEntityManager();
@Override
public List getEmployee(String tableName) {

    String tableName1=tableName;
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select name,age from "+tableName1);
    List userList =new ArrayList();
    try{
        userList= query.getResultList();            
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userList;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no special Array-like element in WSDL. WSDL describes XML structure, and in XML any child element can appear many times, so to differ between single elements/array you specify the `maxOccurs` as more than 1:

```
<xsd:element name="messages" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
```

More about creating **contract-first** services: [Writing Contract-First Web Services](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html)